# Beginning of the partition (~3GB) deleted with "badblocks" command. Is data recovery possible?

Tags: data-recovery, badblocks

I executed `badblocks -wsv` on my windows partition to check for badblocks. I relatively quickly realized I executed it in destructive mode so I aborted the process and only ~3GB of the partition were wiped.

Is any data recovery still possible? There were mainly JPEGs and `.docx` documents i want to recover. How do I do that?

Comment: We really can't say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with **testdisk** and **photorec** from [cgsecurity.org](https://www.cgsecurity.org/).

I am afraid, that testdisk will have problems unless one partition starts after the wiped first 3 GB of the drive.

But photorec can recover a lot without a file system by using the data on the 'disk surface' and identify the start of files by typical signatures for many files types including picture files and document files. This is explained at the cgsecurity web site.

But the files names are lost unless they are stored inside the files, and there is no directory structure. So it is a lot of hard work to identify the files and tell correct files from useless fragments and deleted versions.

Comment: Tried photorec, and it worked! Recovering my stuff now. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Let us hope that the most important data can be recovered.

Comment: Photorec is a file carver, it won't perform any directory structure recovery. It should be used only as a last resort after using proper tools first (like the one in the linked duplicate).